# TLS version used in Azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I need to enforce TLS 1.2 in my Azure key vault. How to know which TLS version does my azure key vault uses ?

Answer (score 3):

See the article [Azure Key Vault security - TLS and HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features#tls-and-https)

> For Azure Key Vault, ensure that the application accessing the Keyvault service should be running on a platform that supports TLS 1.2 or recent version. If the application is dependent on .Net framework, it should be updated as well. You can also make the registry changes mentioned in this article to explicitly enable the use of TLS 1.2 at OS level and for .Net framework. To meet with compliance obligations and to improve security posture, Key Vault will deprecate supporting TLS 1.0, 1.1 starting 31st May 2022.

**EDIT:**
As stated in [Juunas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321585/tls-version-used-in-azure-key-vault#comment126067668_71321731):

> The docs also mention that because the front-end server is shared, they cannot allow customers to enforce minimum TLS versions per Key Vault. It supports TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 currently.

Comment: The docs also mention that because the front-end server is shared, they cannot allow customers to enforce minimum TLS versions per Key Vault. It supports TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 currently.